# Why lowercase 'i' mapped to '?' after doing NLS_UPPER

Tags: sql, oracle, nls, nls-sort

Can someone please explain why lowercase `i` in string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` is mapped to `?` whereas all other alphabets are correctly mapped to corresponding uppercase alphabets.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT="xturkish";

Session altered.

SQL> 
SQL> begin
  2   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NLS_UPPER(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) = '
  3                || NLS_UPPER('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
  4  end;
  5  /
NLS_UPPER(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) = ABCDEFGH?JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Update: If nls_sort is set to BINARY, the mapping happens as expected, lowercase `i` maps to a plane English alphabet `I`

Comment: Let's try to narrow it down. What do you get if you run `select dump('i', dump(upper('i')), dump('I') from dual`? The middle one should be something weird, if you say it produces a question mark on your system.

Comment: This is the output I got `SQL> SELECT DUMP('i'), DUMP(UPPER('i')), DUMP(NLS_UPPER('i')), DUMP('I') FROM dual;

DUMP('I')   DUMP(UPPER('I')) DUMP(NLS_UPPER(' DUMP('I')
----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
Typ=96 Len=1: 105 Typ=96 Len=1: 73 Typ=96 Len=1: 73 Typ=96 Len=1: 73
`

Comment: OK. Let's see what happens if you do all of this in SQL without a surrounding procedure. What happens if you run `select nls_upper('i', 'nls_sort = xturkish') from dual;` ? (Note that the NLS_SORT can be passed as an argument to NLS_UPPER, you don't need to alter the session for that.)

Comment: There too `i` is mapped to `?`

Comment: Does you display character set fully support Unicode? `İ` is a non-standard character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capital `i` in Turkish is `İ` (U+0130: Latin Capital Letter I with Dot Above), see https://codepoints.net/U+0130

> The Turkish alphabet, which is a variant of the Latin alphabet,
>   includes two distinct versions of the letter I, one dotted and the
>   other dotless.
>
> The dotless I, I ı, denotes the close back unrounded vowel sound
>   (/ɯ/). Neither the upper nor the lower case version has a dot.
>
> The dotted I, İ i, denotes the close front unrounded vowel sound
>   (/i/). Both the upper and lower case versions have a dot.
>
> Examples:
>
> - İstanbul /isˈtanbuɫ/ (starts with an i sound, not an ı).
> - Diyarbakır /dijaɾˈbakɯɾ/ (the first and last vowels are spelled and pronounced differently)

Looks like your Database character set does not support this character, what is your Database character set? Check with

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

I assume

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NLS_UPPER(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) = '
   || NLS_UPPER(N'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
```

should work.

You must set your `NLS_LANG` and console codepage properly for correct output. Here are some working examples:

```
C:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>sqlplus ...
select nls_upper('i', 'nls_sort = xturkish') from dual;



C:\>set NLS_LANG=.TR8MSWIN1254
C:\>chcp 1254
Active code page: 1254

C:\>sqlplus ...
select nls_upper('i', 'nls_sort = xturkish') from dual;




C:\>set NLS_LANG=.SE8ISO8859P3
C:\>chcp 28593
Active code page: 28593

C:\>sqlplus ...
select nls_upper('i', 'nls_sort = xturkish') from dual;




C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P9
C:\>chcp 28599
Active code page: 28599

C:\>sqlplus ...
select nls_upper('i', 'nls_sort = xturkish') from dual;
```

Comment: Nice explanation, but it conflicts with my experience. As you can see in my reply, Oracle gladly converted dotted `i` to dotless `I` when I ran exactly what the OP has posted.

Comment: Strange, I get `ABCDEFGHİJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` (captial I with dot) on a database which runs on `AL32UTF8`

Comment: Also, the OP gets `73` for `dump(nls_upper('i'))`. That is undotted `I`.

Comment: Undotted `I` is correct for `upper(ı)`, but `upper(i)`should return dotted `İ`.

Comment: @dnoeth, `UPPER` does not handle special linguistic requirements, you must use `NLS_UPPER` to get the dotted `İ`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Of course, this is what i meant. But mathguy's result showed the undottet `I`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it because I can't reproduce it. Something must be wrong on your machine. Here is my session, copied and pasted from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT="xturkish";

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> begin
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NLS_UPPER(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) = '
  3                  || NLS_UPPER('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'));
  4    end;
  5  /
NLS_UPPER(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz) = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
```

Comment: I wonder, how come it is machine dependent? When I use nls_sort = BINARY, the mapping happens as expected.

Comment: @user1612078 - Not really "machine" dependent, what I said was "**on**" your machine. Something along the lines of Wernfried's answer: character set, NLS settings (other than NLS_SORT), etc.